# cinnamon-screensaver and lock settings not visible in settings panel

Tags: linux-mint, cinnamon

A rather peculiar problem: After updating a fresh installation of Linux Mint Debian Edition, I lost the ability to change the screensaver and lock settings, here's a screenshot of the relevant settings page, completely missing the actual setting options:

[image: Screensaver and Lock Settings]

According to the release notes of the Update Pack 7, the `cinnamon-screensaver` package replaces and removes `gnome-screensaver`, which sounds like the root of the problem. The problem persists even after removing and re-installing `cinnamon-screensaver`, though.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's Cinnamon's view of the screensaver.  Gnome has it's own view in `gnome-control-center` that controls the settings you want.
[image: gnome-control-center]
[image]
Oddly (in Mint Maya at least) both show up in the menu under system tools as "System Settings" making it extra confusing.  I ended up renaming one "Gnome Settings"

Comment: Thanks, this solved the issue. Pretty frustrating and not very user friendly, isn't it? :)